# Is it better to ask people one direct important question, or several indirect questions, when asking for help?

Tags: support, asking-questions

I am hoping to understand the line between patience and efficiency in spiritual matters.

Is it better to ask people one direct important question or several indirect questions, when asking on Stack Exchange for help?

Answer (score 6):

First of all, Welcome!

Your question should be clear and not contain too many questions which may give rise to many possible answers. It is always better to ask one question per post rather than posting many indirect or related questions. Asking many question may confuse the readers of your question. By asking a single question in a post, you can focus on your doubt more clearly. Users who are giving answers will also be able to give complete answers rather than partial answers.

If a question contains multiple indirect (even though related) questions, chances of getting [closed or put on hold](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions) are high.

From [How do I ask a good question?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask),

> **Be specific**
>
> If you ask a vague question, you’ll get a vague answer. But if you give us details and context, we can provide a useful answer.

You can ask a new question in a separate post again.

Read [Can I ask only one question per post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/222735/357396) This is really detailed and explains why asking many questions is a disadvantage.

Please visit [Help Center](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help) of Hinduism Stack Exchange. Read the [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) to know the site policies.
All the best!!